# IIS ASP Integrated Pipeline mode not calling the right module when URL end with a "static" filename

Tags: asp.net, iis, integrated-pipeline-mode

I have a module that is acting as a "proxy".  It's needed to resolve some cross domain scripting issues I had.  So the server will get the outside content and give it back to the client, and the client is staying within the same domain.

My issue is when there is a "static file" name at the end of the url, my handler is not getting called...  Here is an example:

```
 http://my.url.com/myproxy.ashx/site1/getsomestuff.aspx?parm1=value1
```

I get an HTTP error 404 File Not Found for url myproxy.ashx/site1/getsomestuff.aspx

BUT, if I mangle the URL above so there is no dotted filename at the end of the URL like this:

```
 http://my.url.com/myproxy.ashx/site1/getsomestuff_aspx?parm1=value1
```

The handler for myproxy.ashx gets called.  If I then put some kludge code to change getsomestuff_aspx to getsomestuff.aspx when I generate the URL to actually query - I've gotten it to work.  But I am pretty sure, especially with Integrated Pipeline mode, that I SHOULD be able to SOMEWHERE say that if the URL has "myproxy.ashx/" somewhere in it, then call my handler module...  Can someone point me in the right direction...

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this one out:
Added the following inside the  system.webServer node of web.config:

> ```
>  <handlers>   <add name="ProxyAll" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,POST" path="myproxy.ashx*" type="MyNameSpace.MyProxy"/> </handlers>
> ```

The  * after myproxy.ashx will match all the URLs even with static file names at the end.